# About figure in minipage

Tags: floats, minipage

How to hide "Figure 3:" and "Figure 4:", and let "Figure 5" shows as "Figure 3"? (i.e. subfigure not taking the figure number)

```
\begin{figure}[htbp]
\hspace{-4mm}
\begin{minipage}{0.5\linewidth}]
\centering
\input{trans}
\caption{(a)}
\end{minipage}
\begin{minipage}{0.5\linewidth}
\centering
\input{trans1}
\caption{(a)}
\end{minipage}
\caption{Monitoring Automata}
\label{fig:monitoringAutomata}
\end{figure}
```

[image]

Comment: Why don't you use `subfloat` from `subfig` package?

Answer (score 8):

If I understand what you're asking for, I think this should do the trick:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[htbp]
    \hspace{-4mm}
    \begin{minipage}{0.5\linewidth}
        \centering
        \includegraphics[width=2in]{example-image-a}\\
        Info on image (a)
    \end{minipage}
    \begin{minipage}{0.5\linewidth}
        \centering
        \includegraphics[width=2in]{example-image-b}\\
        Info on image (b)
    \end{minipage}
    \caption{Monitoring Automata}
    \label{fig:monitoringAutomata}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

I don't have your image files.  So I use the package `graphicx` to import different images.  In other words the `graphicx` package is not necessary to the solution.

The key here is that I'm not using a caption on the images.  I've just got a *title* centered below each.

The numbering for the figure is *off* only because this *is* the first figure in my document.  If you copy this into your document, the numbering of the figure should be as you want it.